# Can I use Dropbox to back the auto-update feature for my application?

Tags: dropbox, auto-update, software-distribution

I want to add an auto-update feature for my application, but I don't have a server or a good host for making this feature. Can I use Dropbox or any other free services to add this feature to my programs?

Comment: Bad idea. Instead, get yourself a real web hosting suit. They are very cheap. For instance, I only pay some 80 USD/year for rejbrand.se, algosim.se, including both the domain names, several GBs of disk space, unlimited number of subdomains, unlimited number of e-mail addresses, several kinds of server-side scripting possibilities, advanced statistics, webmail, FTP upload/download, etc.

Comment: (Hint: Divide 80 USD/year by 365.25 days/year to find 0.22 USD/day. That's essentially 'for free'.) [Also, I forgot the 'e' in the last post. Sorry.]

Comment: Regardless of whether you *can*, do you really want your product's distribution to rely on a service that may terminate your account "at any time, with or without notice"?

Comment: Not that I recommend them (I don't), but GoDaddy will give you free hosting for life that you can use for mere file storage with every domain purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is nothing in the Dropbox terms and conditions to forbid you from using it to distribute updates for your software. I you want legal advice on what you can and cannot do, then please consult a lawyer, not a bunch of programmers.

Comment: i didn't ask about the legal advice !! i was asking about Can i use Dropbox service as a tiny server ? that's it

Comment: If you really meant to ask whether you *can* use Dropbox, and not whether you *may* use it, then I'll have to vote to close your question as *too localized* because nobody can tell you what your own personal capabilities are, and nobody else cares what the answer is, either. Files on Dropbox have URLs, and programs can be written to download resources from URLs; are you capable of storing files on Dropbox, learning their URLs, and writing code to make a program download from there? If you want to learn *how*, then ask *how*.

Comment: Thanks i got my answer now :)